# Vuejs console logs appear then disappears in chrome

Tags: vue.js

I have created a new VueJs project with `vue-router` and `ESLint`.
When I load the page with the console log open I can see `console.log` outputs for few milliseconds then they disappear. If I close developer tools and reopen, they reappear and stay until the page is refreshed.

This is only an issue in Chrome, Firefox is fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `Preserve Log` option in DevTools?

Answer (score -1):

The **'Preserve log**' will be under the settings icon in chrome.